# gulp-nunjucks-render and adding data from single file

Tags: gulp, nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

How can I include data to gulp-nunjucks template from separate file?

```
//template/data/data.html

{% set 
list = [
    {
        title: 'Item1'
    },
    {
        title: 'Item2'
    }
] 
%}
```

This simple solution doesn't work.

```
{% include "data/json.html" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you use import instead of include, https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#import

Try this (I used `.njk` extensions, but you can use `.html`, it won't matter):

```
//template/data/data.njk

{% set list = [
  {
    title: 'Item1'
  },
  {
    title: 'Item2'
  }] %}
```

And in the file where you want to use the `{{ list }}` variable:

```
//template/other-file.njk

{% from 'data/data.njk' import list %}
{{ list }}
```

Any top-level variables that are `{% set %}` or any macros that are defined are available via `import`.